# SQL Manager for MySQL - select inserts empty row

Tags: mysql, sql-manager

I have a very weird situation here. During development I discovered that one of my tables got more and more empty rows (the Id field is auto-incremented and was set). No insert statement was run from my code.

I use SQL Manager 2010 Lite for MySQL to inspect the data, and it turns out that when I Execute the select statement from there, the empty row gets added.

Has anyone else experienced this? All i do is right click the table, select 'Script to NEW SQL Editor' and Select. When I press Execute, the row gets added.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer - I'm using phpmyadmin myself - but you could try setting one of the columns to not null? Just to see what happens, and what kind of error message you get? And you could also check to see if there are any stored procedures that could cause this.

Normally I would post this in a comment, but I don't have enough rep to do that yet, sorry...

Comment: Tried this now, and it just adds a '0' to the row in the NOT NULL column